# Something very strange with network

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have Windows 7 and I have very strange thing with my network.
Some time I was connected through wireless router and my IP was 192.168.2.103, router's IP was 192.168.2.1 and some other IP was 192.168.2.100. The last I get from page "active DHCP clients" of web interface of the router and from "wireless clients" I may to see that 192.168.2.100 not (!) belong to my MAC address. Router build by EDimax.
So after that I disabled wireless function of the router and restarted it. In this time I had not ping to 192.168.2.1. Also I had not any other connection, not wireless nor cable, but (!) I still had ping to 192.168.2.100 and I not understand what this voodoo is...

```
C:\Users\Andrey>ping 192.168.2.100

Pinging 192.168.2.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.2.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.2.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.2.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.100:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

This is what I had:

```
C:\Users\Andrey>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Andrey-PC
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WIFI Miniport Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 06-1D-7D-40-61-EB
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : GBabyte GN-WS50G (mini) PCI-E WLAN Card
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1D-7D-40-61-EB
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8055 PCI-E GBabit Ethernet Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1B-24-B6-09-91
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\Andrey>arp -a -v

Interface: 127.0.0.1 --- 0x1
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
224.0.0.22                                  static
239.255.255.250                             static

Interface: 0.0.0.0 --- 0xffffffff
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.2.1           00-0e-2e-d2-8c-af     invalid
192.168.2.255         Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-Firefox-fa     static
255.255.255.255       Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox     static

Interface: 0.0.0.0 --- 0xffffffff
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.2.1           00-0e-2e-Firefox-f1-f6     dynamic
192.168.2.101         00-27-19-bc-8b-9c     dynamic
192.168.2.102         00-16-e6-6c-ae-d4     dynamic
192.168.2.255         Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-Firefox-fa     static
255.255.255.255       Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox     static

Interface: 0.0.0.0 --- 0xffffffff
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
255.255.255.255       Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox-Firefox     static

C:\Users\Andrey>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
14...06 1d 7d 40 61 eb ......Microsoft Virtual WIFI Miniport Adapter #2
13...00 1d 7d 40 61 eb ......GBabyte GN-WS50G (mini) PCI-E WLAN Card
11...00 1b 24 b6 09 91 ......Marvell Yukon 88E8055 PCI-E GBabit Ethernet Controller
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None
```

Only after reboot I lost ping to there:

```
C:\Users\Andrey>ping 192.168.2.100

Pinging 192.168.2.100 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.100:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

So what is this mysterious cache?

Answer (score 0):

Your default route points to the loopback interface. Since the loopback interface will loop anything back to you (regardless which IP) and does not care about MAC addresses, every (non-Multicast) address should have been pingable at that point - and always answered by your own machine.

Comment: Thank you for replay. But why 192.168.2.1 wasn't pingable at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rodnower :) If you had disconnected all types of network interfaces, you computer must not ping anywhere ever. However there is no loopback seems to be installed, depending on your ipconfig data.

First of all, try to remove through device manager all the types of network devices (wireless and wired(cable)).

Also check that you don't have any records in hosts file.

---

P.S. What for "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2" you have? (Try to remove it... and check again)

Comment: Thank you for replay :) but I already can't to check it... It was so long ago...

Comment: ahh ok, sorry didn't pay attention to the date (the system/or moderator has upped this question due no accepted answer, yet).